# Testing for Continuity using Sandwich Theorem

Tags: limits, continuity

Given the function
$ f(n) =
\begin{cases}
x\sin (1/x),  & x \neq 0 \\
0, & x=0
\end{cases} $

describe the interval on which the function is continuous.

This function is a similar one to the one I asked about recently but the oscillations are damped by a factor of x

The solution says that you use the sandwich theorem to get:

$-|x| \leq x\sin (1/x) \leq |x|$, where  $x\neq 0$

I was confused on where it got the $|x|$ in the inequality.

Comment: The inequality uses $|x|$ because $\sin\theta$ varies from $-1$ to $1$

Comment: Where did the 7 come from?

Comment: @XanderHenderson not supposed to be these. Removed it, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Notice that
$$ -1 \le \sin(\theta) \le 1, $$
regardless of the value of $\theta$.  This means that for any value of $x$ (other than zero), we have
$$ -1 \le \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \le 1. $$
We would like to hit this inequality with a factor of $x$, but there is a slight problem:  multiplication by a negative number reverses the direction of the inequalities.  So, we can work in cases:

- If $x > 0$, then
  $$ -1 \le \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \le 1
  \implies -x \le x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \le x.$$
  Since $x > 0$, we have $|x| = x$, and so this inequality *can* be written as
  $$ -|x| \le x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \le |x|. $$
- If $x < 0$, then
  $$ -1 \le \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \le 1
  \implies -x \ge x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \ge x
  \implies x \le x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \le -x. $$
  Here, $x < 0$, and so $|x| = -x$ (which implies that $-|x| = x$).  Thus the inequality can *also* be written as
  $$ -|x| \le x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \le |x|.$$

In either case, we obtain the desired result, and can apply the Squeeze (Sandwich) Theorem at zero.